# Want to calculate radius from one position

Tags: mysql, distance, radius, pythagorean

I want to know how to start on my radius filter for a accommodation site. For example I want to know fields I need in my database and the data I will need in it to work out the radius. I want this radius filter to be implemented in my search page when looking for an accommodation. I'm guessing I will need grid coordinates, longitude and latitude. Then implement the Pythagoras's theorem to actually calculate the distance from one position to different postcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd just need the Longitude and Latitude of the location in your database, you'd then need to pass your coordinates into an SQL query to calculate the distance, this can then be sorted by distance and you can choose to show the nearest x number of results.

Something like this should be a good starting point for your SQL query.

```
$qry = "SELECT *,(((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`Latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`Latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `Longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance
FROM `MyTable` WHERE distance >= ".$distance."
```

You can then add in your ORDER BY distance if needed and LIMIT.